# Why i get NAs in my correlation matrix?

Tags: r

I have huge matrix with dimension 39635 * 22. I need to compute the correlation for the row of this matrix. I already checked and there is no NA values in my matrix. But when I compute the correlation, I face with lot's of NAs in my final correlation matrix. Here is the steps which I do:

```
index2<-which( is.na(Gene), arr.ind=TRUE)
> dim(index2)
[1] 0 2
W<-cor(t(Gene))
index<-which( is.na(W), arr.ind=TRUE)
dim(index)
[1] 9972018       2
```

Dose anyone have idea why I get so much NA in my final correlation matrix ?

Comment: can you show us `str(t(Gene))` ?

Comment: I'm curious why you rolled back my edits ... was there any particular thing you objected to?  (You also removed the `str(t(Gene))` information, which was useful.)  I thought my edits were useful, but I don't feel like getting into an edit war.

Answer (score 1):

(Not necessarily an answer, but way too long for a comment ...)

So far I can't replicate; it could (?) conceivably be something about very large matrices, but I run out of memory first.

```
nafun <- function(nrows,ncols=22,
                  rfun=runif) {
    Gene <- matrix(runif(nrows*ncols),ncol=ncols)
    W <- cor(t(Gene))
    sum(which(is.na(W)))
}
set.seed(101)
nafun(1000)   ## 0
nafun(5000)   ## 0
nafun(10000)  ## 0
nafun(20000)  ## Error: cannot allocate vector of size 3.0 Gb
nafun(10000,rfun=rnorm) ## 0
nafun(15000,rfun=rnorm) ## Error: cannot allocate vector of size 858.3 Mb
```

Is it possible that you have non-finite but not-`NA` values in your data set? Worth trying

```
summary(c(Gene))
any(is.finite(Gene))
```

as well.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility could be columns in your matrix that are constant. Here's an example with no missing data that generates `NA` values due to this problem:

```
(m <- rbind(1:2, c(1, 3)))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    2
# [2,]    1    3
cor(m)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1   NA
# [2,]   NA    1
# Warning message:
# In cor(m) : the standard deviation is zero
```

You could identify if this is the issue based on the warning message it produces, or you could run something like `table(apply(t(Gene), 2, sd) == 0)`.

Comment: good possibility. I *hope* the OP wouldn't neglect to tell us about warning messages, but they might have ...